# Extracting U.S. common law case names (e.g., Smith v. Jones) systematically using off-the-shelf NLP software?

Tags: regex, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I'd like to find a way to extract case names from U.S. courts from sentences. They usually take a predictable pattern, although I think they may be too varied to capture well with Regexs, so I was thinking about using NLP to locate them.

Here are a few examples of case names (bolded) as they might be used in partial sentences:

- In **United States v. George**, the Court held that...
- **In re. Bankruptcy of Sir Walter Williams, III** is a case from the Southern District of New York...
- Not only is **Ashcroft v. Iqbal**, 556 U.S. 662 (2009) incorrectly decided, it also...
- The Court's recent decision in **Burwell v. Hobby Lobby Stores**, No. 13-354 (U.S. Jun 30, 2014) implicates First Amendment rights...
- The case of **Trans World Airlines, Inc. v. Flight Attendants** was correctly decided...

I've been experimenting with off-the-shelf packages (like TextBlob for Python), which helps do things like extract noun phrases -- I just don't know how to take the next step and recognize case names as a unit.

Comment: There's definitely no way to differentiate the bold substrings above from the rest using regex.

Comment: Yeah, that was my feeling as well, which is why I think/hope there may be an NLP-based solution.

Comment: Seems like a tough ask for even that, good luck.

Comment: Naïve (but fast!) heuristics attempt, which assumes that most/all names look like the ones in your examples. You can try it on a subset of your data and see how well it works - use _v._ and _re._ as anchors and expand the regex from there (to both sides in the case of _v._, and to the right in the case of _re._) until you find any of "_,_", "_re._" (when anchoring on _v._), or an uncapitalized word (assuming that these named entities are Title Cased).

Comment: Otherwise, some form of [named entity recognition](http://textminingonline.com/how-to-use-stanford-named-entity-recognizer-ner-in-python-nltk-and-other-programming-languages) may be somewhat helpful, but it will likely require [some training](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, @arturomp. I'll try the naive approach -- it may yield 80-90% of what we need. And when we want to get more specific, I can look into training.

Comment: You can try using an off the shelf named entity recognizer (the NLTK includes a decent one). The named entities in your corpus are probably people, companies and organizations, which are all pretty standard. It's then an easy matter to regognize the pattern `(NE) v. (NE)`. For the rest, it depends. What makes `In re. Bankruptcy of Sir Walter Williams, III` a regular case-naming pattern?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
((re\.).*?,.*?\b(?<=\s)(?=[a-z]))|(?!\r|\n|\.)((\s\m[A-Z][a-z]+?\M\s).*?v\.\s.*?\b[A-Z].*?[a-z]\M)(?!\s[A-Z])|Ex\sparte\s\b[A-Z].*?[a-z](?=(\.|,|;|\s))
```

It's imperfect in that it doesn't capture *only* the bolded text (it might grab a little more, but it won't match a false-positive (as it needs to find the v.)), but it's guaranteed to find all the provided examples, plus all the Ex parte  cases too that I gleaned from Wiki

There are three capture groups in this regex:
1. Matches with **v.**
2. Matches with **re.**
3. Matches with **Ex parte**

ps: this is generic PCRE regex pattern syntax. Most program/scripting languages and many of the more advanced text editors should find matches using this.

Comment: Yes, this is a good start with RegExs, and along the lines of what we were hoping to do ourselves (and nice work adding the Ex Parte). I was hoping an NLP solution would be more robust, but maybe it's not something that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Illinois  Wikifier will get most of these cases for you: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/wikify/?id=25

Comment: I think that's generally right of very famous cases (like the ones I used as examples), but there are lots of cases that have not been wikified yet. I also tried running this through the Illinois Wikifier, and it only got one right (Ashcroft v. Iqbal).

Comment: Well, yes. It really depends whether your mentions appear in Wiki or not, but anyways I thought it might give you something ....